# Excel - INDIRECT with count

Tags: excel

I am working on creating a summary sheet template dynamically updating from various sheets.

- The sheets are named by dates (i.e `1-9-2017`, `2-9-2017`, `3-9-2017`,...)
- Each sheet has columns arranged uniformly (i.e `contact_date`, `lead_qualification`, `sales person`, etc.)
- Values in the `lead_qualification` column can either be `Yes` or `No`.

I want to count all the qualified leads (`Yes`) for the month on the summary_sheet from all the sheets.

I have tried the formula below but still getting `#REF!` error.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&B6&"'!"&'1-9-2016'!$F$2:$F$63),"Yes")
```

Where `B6` is the sheet_name and `'1-9-2016'!$F$2:$F$63` is the cell range on the first sheet.

Comment: Do you mean sheets, or workbooks? Is it 1 workbook and different sheets, or different workbooks?

Comment: It would help greatly if you would type in the first several rows of one of your sheets. Although you have taken great pains to describe the sheet, it might take ten minutes or so to set up. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to aid in forming a reproducible problem.

Comment: Unfortunately COUNTIF isn't supported as a 3D formula.  A (not ideal) workaround that I found: Create a named range containing each sheet name - in my example it's SheetList which contains the values 1-9-2017, 2-9-2017, 3-9-2017.  You can then use `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!F2:F63"),"Yes"))`.  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/224433-why-am-i-getting-error-countif-3d-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` requires a string, and only a string. Some of your entered terms, e.g. the `"!"`, don't appear to be in a string of their own. As well, Rather than using `INDIRECT('"&B6&"'!"&'1-9-2016'!$F$2:$F$63)`, where the last part (the range) isn't entered as a string, the range needs to be in quotes.

Finally, I'm unsure why you've seemingly hard-coded in `1-9-2016`, since that seems like a value that should be varying based on what's in `B6` or the like. Overall, I think this would become `INDIRECT(B6&"!"&"$F$2:$F$63")`. This will ensure that the range is entirely entered as a string, clean up some of the other issues, and thus hopefully the  `INDIRECT` will work fine.